# How to skip git merging a certain file, when merging between branches

Tags: git

How to skip git merging a certain file, when merging between branches

```
src/main/resources/application.properties in development branch contains ENV for dev
src/main/resources/application.properties in staging branch contains ENV for staging
```

git checkout staging
git merge origin/development - overrides the above file, which I don't want to. How should I prevent this

Comment: if the file contents are env-specific they should not be in git; This may be a useful read/reference https://12factor.net (TLDR code should be env-agnostic, read config as env vars)

Answer (score 0):

1. `git merge --no-commit`
2. edit/revert the file to what you want it to be
3. `git add src/main/resources/application.properties`
4. `git commit`

Comment: Note that this means that when you merge from staging back to development, the copy in the staging branch will overwrite the one in development. Not sure if that's what you want or not.

Comment: Probably worth calling out, from the context in the question, that there is no good git solution.